# How does one maintain a data structure (NOT A DATABASE) like an array that is accessible by other threads

Tags: java, arrays, list, sockets, data-structures

So I am making a server-client application where a client will communicate with the server using sockets. I have the server create a thread for each client request for communication, so all input/output to the client is handled by the thread. I want to create a data structure, say a simple list that is accessible by other threads, so they can store and retrieve information to and from the server for the client. Here is part of my code:

So here I start the server client

```
package shapeserver;

/**
 *
 * @author malus
 */
public class ShapeServer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SocketServer s = new SocketServer();
        s.runServer();
    }
}
```

---

Here I accept incoming requests and pass them to a thread to handle the requests

```
package shapeserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author malus
 */
class SocketServer {
    int portNumber = 4444;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    void runServer() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber); 
            System.out.println("Server is online...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new ShapeRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here the requests are handled by the thread, for now I am simply sending back the data user puts in just to test out the connection for input/output

```
package shapeserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author malus
 */
public class ShapeRunnable implements Runnable {
    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    private Shape shape;

    public ShapeRunnable(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while (true) {
                String argList [];
                String arg;
                arg = in.readLine();
                if (arg.equals("done")) {
                    out.println("Goodbye.");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    out.println("You entered "+arg);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

---

Here is what the client sees

```
package shapeclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author malus
 */
public class ShapeClient {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostName;
        int portNumber;
        Socket clientSocket;
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in;
        InputStreamReader ir;
        BufferedReader stdIn;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Client Program.");
        System.out.println("Enter Host: ");
        hostName = reader.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Port Number: ");
        portNumber = reader.nextInt();
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
            // create out IO streams
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            ir = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(ir);
            stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String arg;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Enter Shape:");
                arg = stdIn.readLine();
                out.println(arg.toLowerCase());
                System.out.println("Server says "+in.readLine());
                if (arg.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) break;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

So my question is if I want to extend on this to have the user enter data and I want to have the thread store the data somewhere on the server that is accessible by other threads, how do I go about doing this? I am still new to Java so I am not sure how global variables across classes are handled, or how I would go about accessing a list from classes outside of the current class.

Comment: Variables across classes work perfectly fine. Accessing with threads is an issue and there's synchronized list objects via `Collections.synchronizedList`. But if the server goes down, you loose everything, so you use a database

Comment: That is fine, the data can be volatile. I just need to access it while the server is on.

Comment: also I was under the impression that I would need to use threads to do multiple clients. Is it possible to serve multiple clients without threads?

Comment: One thread per client allows you to scale the application to handle increased traffic, so that's a good thing, but broader than the initial question